# Level height doesn't match the starting print height

Tags: z-axis, creality-cr-10

I have a Creality CR-10. Every time I go to level the printer and start printing, the starting print height is way higher. After I adjust the height, the filament looks weird when printed, smaller or squished almost.

I don't see a setting that looks incorrect and I have printed this item and many others before. I don't know how to fix it. I have cleaned the nozzle, changed the filament and the filament tube. I don't want to drop a lot of money on a new one but I'm struggling to figure it out.

Comment: Can you put a little more detail in your question on how this leveling and adjustment of the height is done. Also photos of the squish may be helpful.